# How to set the good PATH of apache2ctl in sh environemeent of Docker

Tags: docker, apache2

Here my Dockerfile :

```
FROM debian

ENV APACHE_RUN_USER www-data
ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP www-data
ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/web/log/apache2
ENV APACHE_PID_FILE /var/run/apache2.pid
ENV APACHE_RUN_DIR /var/run/apache2
ENV APACHE_LOCK_DIR /var/lock/apache2

#RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive && apt-get update && apt-get -y -q upgrade && apt-get -y -q install apache2
RUN  apt-get update && apt-get -y -q upgrade && apt-get -y -q install apache2

EXPOSE 80 443

CMD  ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl","-D","FOREGROUND","&"]
```

When I launch my container the system is calling apache2 in place of apache2ctl and I've got this error message :

```
:~/strech_apache$ docker container run -ti -p 80:80 system/strech_apache
Usage: /usr/sbin/apache2 [-D name] [-d directory] [-f file]
                         [-C "directive"] [-c "directive"]
                         [-k start|restart|graceful|graceful-stop|stop]
                         [-v] [-V] [-h] [-l] [-L] [-t] [-T] [-S] [-X]
Options:
  -D name            : define a name for use in <IfDefine name> directives
.../...
    Action '-D FOREGROUND &' failed.
    The Apache error log may have more information.
```

When I ran my Dockerfile as container without the `CMD` line in interactive mode, I'm able to launch the `apache2ctl -D FOREGROUND &` and I've got the default apache page working.

**UPDATE**

When I did my Dockefile with the `CMD` line as following :

```
CMD ["apache2ctl","-D","FOREGROUND"]
```

My error message changed like this :

```
system@vmdebian:~/strech_apache$ docker container run -ti -p 80:80 system/strech_apache:strech
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
system@vmdebian:~/strech_apache$
```

Same if I wrote my CMD like this :

```
CMD  ["service","apache2","restart"]
```

I've got this message

```
system@vmdebian:~/strech_apache$ docker container run -ti -p 80:80 system/strech_apache:strech 
[....] Restarting Apache httpd web server: apache2AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
. ok
```

It's look like apache switch on/off and the container is stopped with the stop of apache2

How to get apache2 still running ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the final `"&"` argument from your `CMD`.

There's two underlying issues here, and removing the `&` fixes both:

When you use the `CMD ["command", "arg", "..."]` form, Docker does not run a shell at all; it just directly runs the command and passes in the arguments it's given.  Your `CMD` runs `apache2ctl` with three arguments, `-D`, `FOREGROUND`, and `&`.  `apache2ctl` launches `apache2` with the arguments it's given, but it doesn't understand `&` as an argument, which is the error you're getting.

Also, your `CMD` (or `ENTRYPOINT`) must run its process *as a foreground process*.  If you type a command at your shell and immediately get a shell prompt back, if you try to make that command the main command in a container, the container will exit immediately when you start it.  You don't want the usual shell "run in the background" meaning of `&` here; you want Apache to run as a foreground process and the container to run as long as Apache is running.

Comment: I did an update I'm thinking I did  not explain the problem well

Comment: `service` essentially doesn’t work in Docker, for the same reason as in my last paragraph.  I wonder if you need `-DFOREGROUND` as a single argument.